# load vrml in an angular project using three-full

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to load vrml(wrl) file in browser using three-full and angular 6.

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import * as THREEFULL from 'three-full';
import * as THREE from 'three';

//var STLLoader = require('three-stl-loader')(THREE);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('rendererContainer') rendererContainer: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('inset') inset: ElementRef;

      ngOnInit() {

        // var loader = new STLLoader();
        // loader.load('assets/stls/Chiller.stl', data=>{});
        var loader = new THREEFULL.VRMLLoader();
        loader.load('assets/stls/house.wrl', data=>{});
      }    
}
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isRecordingFaces' of undefined
>
> at parseProperty (Three.es.js:79995)
>
> at getTree (Three.es.js:80315)
>
> at parseV2 (Three.es.js:80799)
>
> at VRMLLoader.parse (Three.es.js:80866)
>
> at Object.onLoad (Three.es.js:79822)
>
> at XMLHttpRequest. (Three.es.js:21802)
>
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
>
> at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
>
> at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
>      at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)

It seems that loading a wrl file causes already the error.
Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace and more parts of your code. One variable is undefined, so something is not initialized properly. Can you trace down the problem to a specific line by commenting out single lines and checking whether the error persists

Comment: Hi, I minimized my code and posted the full trace.
If I use STLLoader, which is commented, there is no error.